# morphisms in $Vect_k^\otimes$

Tags: category-theory

Let $Vect_k^\otimes$ be the tensor category of finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces with the tensor product. What is an example of a morphism $f: V \to W$ in $Vect_k$ which is *no* morphism in $Vect_k^\otimes$?

Answer (score 2):

The morphisms of ${\rm Vect}_k^\otimes$ *are exactly the same* morphisms as in ${\rm Vect}_k$. 
The tensor category has *additional structure*, compared to the plain category ${\rm Vect}_k$, namely the tensor functor
$$\otimes:{\rm Vect}_k\times{\rm Vect}_k\ \to\ {\rm Vect}_k\,,$$
which is associative up to isomorphism and has a unit.

Comment: Thank you. I want to determine the automorphism group of the forgetful functor $Vect_k^\otimes \to Vect_k$. (It should be trivial.) Since the automorphism group of the identity functor $Vect_k \to Vect_k$ is $k^\times$, what is the additional structure for $Vect_k^\otimes$ that eliminates the extra automorphisms?

Comment: Hmm.. who said that it is trivial? Is it sure that by 'automorphism group of the forgetful functor' it is meant the group of invertible natural transformations? The same $\lambda\cdot\ :\ V\to V$ should define a natural transformation for $\lambda\in k^\times$..

Comment: @user: the automorphisms of the forgetful functor as a functor are different from the automorphisms of the forgetful functor as a *tensor* functor (these are the automorphisms relevant for Tannaka-Krein duality, which I assume is what you're studying). That is, it's the functor that has extra structure. You might find http://mathoverflow.net/questions/155743/can-one-explain-tannaka-krein-duality-for-a-finite-group-to-a-computer-ho useful.